# admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_feature_product 403 error

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-403

i have a wordpress with woocommerce plugin
but when i trying to set featured some product on woocommerce product page that star used to set featured item show yes but in phpmyadmin there is no change on _featured of the item
i use firefox inspect element in the network tap when i click on star buttom i got 302 error on:"wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_feature_product&product_id=74&_wpnonce=2bd42dcb1e"
i disable all other plugins and there is no change in functions.php of my theme
i realy dont know why this happen
befor the woocommerce major update(ver 3) every thing is ok but after that i cant featured some item.
my woocommerce ver: 3.0.3
my wordpress ver: 4.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WooCommerce v3.0 featured items are not tracked by meta any more they are now Taxonomy. That's why you don't see the featured meta getting updated.

> Featured products are also using the new product_visibility taxonomy instead of meta which improves queries on those.

Read the blog [here](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/say-hello-to-woocommerce-3-0-bionic-butterfly/)